# How to change table names with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

> **Edit 04/11:** The issue has been resolved following the link given in the original post's comments, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to somehow change the name of the tables generated by Entity Framework in the solution.

I'm trying to migrate my app's database from a Windows (IIS) server to a Linux (Debian) one.

I've set up the server correctly, PHPMyAdmin is working, the database has been cloned to the new server, however I ran into a problem during testing.

I've changed my connection string in the Web.config file, can connect properly to the new server, but when I tried my app in debug mode, I got errors like that:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'database.Users' doesn't exist
```

If I switch back to my old connection string (basically the old server on IIS, it works alright. The "Users" table doesn't exist, it's called "users" in both servers. I think the problem comes down to linux being case-sensitive on the table names, while IIS isn't. I think the trouble here comes from ASP.NET Identity, that sets wrong names for the table, however I have no idea where to change that so my app can work on the new database.

I tried, just for fun, changing the table name to Users, but then it asked me to change some other tables, related to Identity I presume, like UserClaims, UserLogins, Roles and such. All of them were in lowercase in my db. So I changed them, got past the login form, but the next page told me that the table "database.users" didn't exists. So basically it seems that my code states 2 names for 1 table.

Is there a way to correct this issue?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thanks for that, didn't really know how to search for it. It worked. However, I'd still like to know if there's a way to change the name of the tables called from the Entity Framework so I'll leave my question open.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.  I have no experience with Entity so maybe someone else that has some insight will chip in.  You might want to change the title to specifically state "How to change table names with Entity Framework" so it might catch the attention of someone that has knowledge in that area.

Comment: If you're using Code First, you can specify the table name using [Data Annotations - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn). If the database already exists and you need to change the table names, then have a look at [Code First Migrations - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx)